# Study permit refusal

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, ghanaian-citizens

My name is Kwasi Cobina, I completed High School in 2015 with a business background, and am currently supporting my uncle in his business since he has been the one who has been supporting my education from infancy.I got an acceptance letter from one of the most prestigious universities in Canada to offer Bachelor in Business Administration. Unfortunately, I applied for the study permit visa and my visa was refused.

Please, I need help Because I want to reapply again I was refused due to the following reasons:

> I am not satisfied that you will leave Canada at the end of your stay
>   as a temporary resident, as stipulated in paragraph 179 (b) of the
>   IRPR,
>
> 1. Based on your family ties in Canada and in your home residents
> 2. Based on Purpose of your visit
> 3. Based on your financial assets and financial status
> 4. Based on your travel history

With my family ties, my uncle said in his sponsorship letter that I will leave Canada after my studies and come back to Ghana, and manage his business with the managerial skills acquired from Canadian environment.

Talking about my financial assets and financial status, I wrote it in my Purpose of Study that I am not working as a permanent worker. I am only supporting my uncle in his business to acquire the basics of administration skills and he is the one who will be paying my tuition fees and other expenses which will be incurred. I provided his business statement showing a balance of USD 100,000, his business documents, letter of sponsorship, and my personal bank statement with a balance of USD 2,000.

And with the travel history, I haven't travelled to any country before which means I have no travel experience does it mean I can't apply?

Please how do I respond to this concern?